# Difference between dates in rows within a same table

Tags: ms-access

```
|ID      |AN      |CRN      |CRT      |SD       |ED 
+-------------------------------------------------------------------
|1       |a       |x        |R        |01-Aug-10| 09-Sep-10
|1       |a       |y        |R        |10-Sep-10| 08-Dec-10 
|1       |a       |z        |R        |20-Dec-10| 
|1       |a       |z        |S        |01-Aug-10| 31-Jan-10
|1       |a       |v        |S        |01-Feb-10| 
|2       |b       |d        |S        |01-Aug-10| 29-Aug-10
|2       |b       |d        |S        |31-Aug-10|
```

This is what Iam looking for from the above table. I want to get the difference between sd and ed . the query should look if the ID is same and if it is same then it should look the CRT is same and if they are same then it should show the difference else it should 0, so the query need to check every row.. Now if the account is different then the query should default show 0.

So the Result should show something like this

```
|ID      |AN      |CRN      |CRT      |SD       |ED         |Difference
+-------------------------------------------------------------------
|1       |a       |x        |R        |01-Aug-10| 09-Sep-10 |0 *(since this is 1st entry in respect to the CRT within the same ID)*
|1       |a       |y        |R        |10-Sep-10| 08-Dec-10 |1 *(10sept(SD)-9sept(ED))*
|1       |a       |z        |R        |20-Dec-10|           |12 
|1       |a       |z        |S        |01-Aug-10| 31-Jan-10 |0 *(since this is 1st entry in respect to the CRT within the same ID)*
|1       |a       |v        |S        |01-Feb-10|           |1 *(1Feb(SD)-31Jan(ED))*
|2       |b       |d        |S        |01-Aug-10| 29-Aug-10 |0 *(since this is a new ID)*
|2       |b       |d        |S        |31-Aug-10|           |2
```

In the differenc col i only need the difference without the narration mentioned in ().
Please help......

Comment: i want to build a query for this.

Comment: I doubt you've included the full complexity of your data, since you could do what you've shown with `Abs(Not IsNull(ED))`.

Comment: im making a small change to the table and see the complexity added..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to getting this correct is to have a table with a sequential (AutoNumber) key that matches the order you have your rows.  If there is not already a key like that on your table, then you need to insert your values into a new temp table with an AutoNumber field as the key.  I have done that into a table called MyTable with the AutoNumber key called TempID.

Then you need to create a query called PreviousRow with this definition:

```
SELECT [TempID]+1 AS PreviousTempID, MyTable.ID, MyTable.AN, MyTable.CRN, MyTable.CRT, MyTable.SD, MyTable.ED FROM MyTable;
```

Then your result is the following query:

```
SELECT MyTable.ID, MyTable.AN, MyTable.CRN, MyTable.CRT, MyTable.SD, MyTable.ED, IIf([MyTable.ID]=[PreviousRow.ID] And [MyTable.CRT]=[PreviousRow.CRT],DateDiff("d",[PreviousRow.ED],[MyTable.SD]),0) AS Difference FROM MyTable LEFT JOIN PreviousRow ON MyTable.TempID = PreviousRow.PreviousTempID;
```